# No internet connectivity from WSL2 / Ubuntu or Kali linux

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I am having connection problems, when I try to ping (to 8.8.8.8 for example) from Ubuntu or from Kali linux the following appears:
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1071ms

I already tried temporarily disabling the Firewall to see if that would fix it, but I still don't have internet access
I also tried various things that I found on forums, like this, but nothing seems to work

```
# Fix network issues
# Delete auto-generated files
[root @ PC-NAME user] # rm /etc/resolv.conf || true
[root @ PC-NAME user] # rm /etc/wsl.conf || true

# Enable changing /etc/resolv.conf
# Enable extended attributes on Windows drives
[root @ PC-NAME user] # cat << EOF> /etc/wsl.conf
[network]
generateResolvConf = false

[automount]
enabled = true
options = "metadata"
mountFsTab = false
EOF

# Use google nameservers for DNS resolution
[root @ PC-NAME user] # cat << EOF> /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
EOF

/etc/wsl.conf
[network]
generateResolvConf = false

Exit Linux WSL

cmd as admin:
wsl --shutdown
netsh winsock reset
netsh int ip reset all
netsh winhttp reset proxy
ipconfig / flushdns

Windows Search> Network Reset

Restart Windows
```

Does anyone know what else could work? I don't know if it contributes to something because I have little knowledge of networks, but I tried to ping from cmd to the ip address that appears with ifconfig in kali linux and I did have ping, however, from the kali terminal to the ip address listed in Ethernet adapter vEthernet (WSL) there was no result

Comment: Are you using an antivirus other than Windows Defender or a firewall other than Windows Firewall?  Are you using a proxy or other network intercepting device?

Comment: @bk2204 No, just Windows Defender and just Windows firewall, and I am not using a proxy or other network intercepting device

Comment: Did you have any luck resolving?  Do you use any compression on the drive?  For instance, the Windows temp folder or the AppData folder where the distribution is installed?

Answer (score -1):

```
netsh winsock reset 
netsh int ip reset all
netsh winhttp reset proxy
ipconfig /flushdns
```

Then, reboot your machine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).